# CASE statement to separate one column into two

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

If my QueryID column has values 'NU.PN20' and 'NU.FLREF' for a specific account. Then I am only expecting the result to be:

```
PStatus IStatus
3       3
```

Instead of getting the above, I will get something like:

```
PStatus IStatus
    3       5
    5       3
```

I hope that is clear enough. Please assist. Thanks.

```
CASE 
  WHEN AV.QueryID IN ('NU.PN1','NU.PN2') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
  WHEN AV.QueryID = 'NU.PN20' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
  WHEN AV.QueryID = 'NU.PN4' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
  ELSE '5'
END AS [PStatus],
CASE   
 WHEN AV.QueryID = 'NU.FL1' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '2'
 WHEN AV.QueryID = 'NU.FLREF' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '3'
 WHEN AV.QueryID IN ('NU.FL2','NU.FL6') AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '4'
 WHEN AV.QueryID = 'ACNOAVAIL' AND AV.Response = 'Y' THEN '6'
 ELSE '5'
END AS [IStatus]
```

Comment: And want do you want? For value to equal two different strings?

Comment: Could you please add some more information about what you're trying to do and how, exactly, the results you're getting are different?

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data.  Or, better yet, set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: There is no way your query result is `1,5`. You don't even have any condition that throw `1` in `PStatus`. Fix your code and give us sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear,
But here is my answer which is based on common sense:

“Please look at the below result for one account. It is creating extra rows”

I’m assuming that the “Case When” statements are a part of an insert statement,
If you get “extra rows” over the “expected rows”, 
Then your statement is called more than once and you should check the reason for it.

"I think PStatus and IStatus does not have a proper link so it will always include a 5."

If no match is found in the case statements, 
it will include a “5” since it’s declared in your “Else” statement.

Two Action Items:

1. Check the amount of calls to the DB procedure.
2. Check input.

Comment: I edited my question if that helps in better understanding. Thank you.

Comment: The question edit only refers to QueryID values, while the Case statements refers to both QueryID and Response Values, that is noticed by the AND operator. What's the response value in the given input?

Comment: Response needs to be "Y".

Comment: Did you try changing the '=' parameter to a Like '%%' expression? Is there a possibility of spaces or other chars you did not notice? can you give it a shot?

Comment: Those are the exact values and that is what I am looking for so using % really won't help. I think the key is self-join AV table in the FROM statement.

Comment: What I'm saying is if modifying the expression to a like expression will solve the issue and you'll see a 3, it means there are hidden chars you are not considering, that maybe pass from code to the statement, or in other way. I think it's worth a shot before eliminating it completely.

Comment: I see the 3's in both new columns. However, it will just insert a 5 for any values in IStatus and vice versa for PStatus. I will not eliminate the case statement but I think I need to self join AV table in FROM statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69740/discussion-between-y-s-and-bulbul).